# How to get hdmi sound to TV on Asus M3A78-EM computer

Tags: sound, hdmi

No hdmi sound to TV on Asus M3A78-EM computer
While my onboard Radeon HD 3000-3300 series hdmi on my Asus M3A78-EM computer sends great video to the TV, I haven't yet got sound on the TV. I am trying to find easy graphical solutions that works. A solution is needed.

I searched for Dolby in Synaptic and added the Dolby related aften software. Also I have tried various tweaks to Start - Applications - Preferences - Pulse Audio Preferences and other sound software but no success yet in getting sound on the TV.

I have tried everything I can think of with no success and I have found no posts showing success. Hopefully all the work Ubuntu is doing will soon get us sound on the TV.

Answer (score 2):

OP posted:

> Apparently gnome-control-center needs to be installed. If you go to Start - Settings - All - Preferences - Sound - Sound - Output and click on hdmi, sound goes to the TV, if you click on your onboard sound, sound goes to your computer speakers. I have hdmi sound to the TV now.

Comment: "_Apparently gnome-control-center needs to be installed_" means that  OP didn't have it installed by default **or** removed it **or** was/is using some [modified Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/356955/25656)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI application for adjusting sound output: hit start and type "sound", then hit enter.  OR, click the user menu in the top right corner and click system settings, then click sound.  There should be options for both speakers (TV & PC) when the TV is plugged in.